# I need some help to understand this code in java

Tags: java

I stack in this code I do not understand what happens in some of its lines .. I commented next to each line I did not understand it ..

here is the code

```
public class C 
{
    boolean [] b = new boolean[3]; // Is this a vector of size 3 ?
    int count = 0;

    void set(boolean [] x, int i) 
    {
        x[i] = true;
        ++count;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        C ba = new C();
        ba.set(ba.b, 0); // what does ba.b do?
        ba.set(ba.b, 2); // what does ba.b do?
        ba.test();
    }

    void test() 
    {
        if ( b[0] && b[1] | b[2] ) // what is this if statement do?
            count++;
        if ( b[1] && b[(++count - 2)] ) // what is this if statement do?
            count += 7;
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }
}
```

Can you discribe to me what happens there ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean[] b = new boolean[3]` is a boolean array with 3 data points

```
b[0] = true; //or false
b[1] = false; //or true
b[2] = true; //or false
```

`int count = 0;` is a variable of type `int`

`void set(boolean [] x, int i)` sets a `boolean array` to equal true in position one. For example

```
set(b,1)
```

would set the variables to

```
b[1] = true
count = 1
```

`ba` is an instance of your class C. In this case it allows you to call your method `set(boolean [] x, int i)` and your boolean array, `b` from your code

Finally the first if statement `if(b[0]&&b[1]||b[2])` says if(the first position, `b[0]` in b is true **and** either position two, `b[1]`, **or** the third position, `b[2]`, is true) then add one to the count variable.

The second if statement `if(b[1]&&b[++count-2])` says if(the second position in the array, `b[1]`, is true **and** b[count-1] is true) then add 7 to the variable count.

The last line of `test()` says print out the value of the variable count to the command console

**Edit**

A vector is another method of storing values in Java but it is not limited to one datatype, such as `int` or `double`. For example

```
import java.util.*;

public class VectorDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // initial size is 3, increment is 2
      Vector v = new Vector(3, 2);
      System.out.println("Initial size: " + v.size());
      System.out.println("Initial capacity: " +
      v.capacity());
      v.addElement(new Integer(1));
      v.addElement(new Integer(2));
      System.out.println("Capacity after four additions: " +
          v.capacity());

      v.addElement(new Double(5.45));
      System.out.println("Current capacity: " +
      v.capacity());
      v.addElement(new Double(6.08));
      v.addElement(new Integer(7));
      System.out.println("Current capacity: " +
      v.capacity());
      v.addElement(new Float(9.4));
      v.addElement(new Integer(10));
      System.out.println("Current capacity: " +
      v.capacity());
      v.addElement(new Integer(11));
      v.addElement(new Integer(12));
      System.out.println("First element: " +
         (Integer)v.firstElement());
      System.out.println("Last element: " +
         (Integer)v.lastElement());
      if(v.contains(new Integer(3)))
         System.out.println("Vector contains 3.");
      // enumerate the elements in the vector.
      Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();
      System.out.println("\nElements in vector:");
      while(vEnum.hasMoreElements())
         System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement() + " ");
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Whereas an array can only hold one type of data and its size is specified when it is declared. For example

```
int[] intArray = new int[2];
intArray[0] = 1;
intArray[1] = 250;
```

or it can be declared as

```
int[] intArray = {1,250};
```

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_vector_class.htm) for more information on Vectors and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) for more information on Arrays.

Comment: what is the difference between an array and a vector? can you give me an example ? thanks

Comment: @program Basically they are different ways of storing different values

Comment: @program Do you need any more information on that class?

Comment: The program has used `|`.Isn't this a bitwise operator?...It should be comparing bits!

Comment: `||` means **or** in Java so `if(b[0]||b[1])` means if(`b[0]` is `true` or `b[1]` is `true`) then... @MathewsMathai

Comment: Its '|' in the program and not `||`. `|` is bitwise OR operator. `||` is basic OR operator to compare values.

Comment: Yeah!..Cosz `||` is so common.An edit may do the job and maybe a short explanation on bitwise OR will complete the answer.But both `|` and `||` will work in this case..not so much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a debugger, put a break point at C ba = new C(); , and then step through, it will give you an idea of what this code is doing.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is an array of booleans

`ba.b` points to the objects instance variable `b`.

`b[0] && b[1] | b[2]` means if b[0] is true and b[1] is true xor b[3] is true

`b[1] && b[(++count - 2)` means if b[1] is true and b[count  - 1] is true

Answer (score 0):

> > boolean[] b = new boolean[3]; // Is this a vector of size 3 ?

Its an array of fix size holding 3 elements

> > ba.set(ba.b, 0); // what does ba.b do?

It sends reference of array b defined above which holds 3 element, so when you pass that value to set method, it sets b's 0th index to true.

> > ba.set(ba.b, 2); // what does ba.b do?

same as above

> > if (b[0] && b[1] | b[2]) // what is this if statement do?

treat it like (condition1 && condition2)

> > if (b[1] && b[(++count - 2)]) // what is this if statement do?

treat it like (condition1 && condition2) where you are saying if `b[1]` is true and `b[count+1-2]` is true too

Comment: what is the difference between an array and a vector? can you give me an example ? thanks

Comment: @program In java, vector is growable array (size can increase or decrease) while in your case array size is fixed. You could define vector as `Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();`

Comment: So this means that `int [] x= new int [10];` is an array while `int [] x= new int [];` is a vector .. Am I right? thanks

Comment: Nah.. see how i defined vector. Your definition of Vector will give you compile time error. Please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[] b=new boolean[3];
//creates a boolean array of length 3.
Indices-0,1,2
example: b[0]=true;
              b[2]=false;

C ba=new C();
C bc=new C();
```

ba and bc are 2 objects of class `C`.They can also be termed as instances.Now every instance/object of a class has it's own copy of the instance variables and the functions in the class.

That means,object `ba` has it's own copy of the `boolean array b`  and object `bc` has it's own unique copy of `boolean array b`.

You refer to ba's copy of array using 
`ba.b` and bc's copy of array using `bc.b`.

Both the objects have a different copy and therefore,the value of b could be different for both.

```
Example:
b[0]=true; //ba's copy
b[0]=false; //bc's copy
```

Now if that boolean array b was static,it means that only one copy of b is shared between all the objects.So static objects can not be referred using object name.It's referred using class name.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not a clear code.

Specifically:

```
boolean [] b = new boolean[3]; // Is this a vector of size 3 ?
```

Yes, this line define an array of 3 boolean values. Each single value could be accessed by using selector index, starting from 0 (i.e. b[0], b[1], b[2]).

```
ba.set(ba.b, 0); // what does ba.b do?
```

Then, ba is an instance of C class. Using ba.b it is possible to access the array b defined in C. Access to single values it is possible using selectors (i.e. b.ba[0], b.ba[1], b.ba[2]).

```
if ( b[0] && b[1] | b[2] ) // what is this if statement do?
```

This statement verifies a logical condition. In this case the condition is verified if both b[0] and b[1] values are TRUE, or simple b[2] is TRUE. Otherwise the condition is not verified.

```
 if ( b[1] && b[(++count - 2)] ) // what is this if statement do?
```

Really, not a good programming example. This statement verify a  condition but also has a side effect of increment the value of count variable. In this case the condition is verified if both b[1] is TRUE and b[(++count - 2)] are TRUE. If count < 1 the code will exit with a RuntimeException because we are trying to access the array outside the valid range of indexes.

Comment: what is the difference between an array and a vector? can you give me an example ? thanks

Comment: Arrays are statically declared (in this case with 3 elements) an they are native statements of the Java language. Sometimes, in Java, vector reference a specific class in the standard library (i.e. java.util.Vector) that is able to handle arrays that may change dynamically its size.

Comment: The program has used `|`.Isn't this a bitwise operator?...It should be comparing bits!

Comment: @program `|` is a bitwise OR operator.It compares bits.

Comment: Yes, it is a bitwise OR operator. It is not very good coding, but in this case it has the same effect of the logical OR operator '||' (i.e. we are using boolean values)

Answer (score 0):

> `boolean [] b = new boolean[3]; // Is this a vector of size 3 ?`

Yes, this is how you create a new array (allocates memory on heap)

> ```
> C ba = new C();
> ba.set(ba.b, 0); // what does ba.b do?
> ```

`ba` is your instantiated object from class `C`, in the second line you call the object's `set` method, passing `ba.b` which is your object's boolean array of size 3, and an integer (0).

> `if ( b[0] && b[1] | b[2] ) // what is this if statement do?`

So `b[0] && b[1]` will be true only if `b[0]` is true and `b[1]` is also true. Let `c` hold this partial result. The next condition will be `c | b[2]`.
This operation is a bitwise operation, namely XOR. It will be true if the two operands are differs from each other, otherwise it will be false. (ex. true | true = false, false | false = false, but true | false = true)

> `if ( b[1] && b[(++count - 2)] ) // what is this if statement do?`
>   Simply check if both `b[1]` and `b[++count - 2]` are true.

`++count` means increasing the count value by one before evaluating it. Assume `count = 2`. Then the right side is `b[1]`.